# Update field IEnumerable regarding duplicates c# EF

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
sqlQuery = 'SELECT MPID, MAPPOINT, X, Y, MPCODE, MultipleSite = 0 FROM MAPPOINT'
 var data = context.Database.SqlQuery<WayPoint>(sqlQuery).ToList();
```

I've pasted the result below.

I'd like to update this result and set `MultipleSite` Column to 1 in case there are other rows that has the same `X` and `Y` values.

For example: records 2 and 3 have the same `X` and `Y` values, So I would like to update the value of their column `MultipleSite` to 1.
Do I have to iterate the result and do some comparison, or I can do it any other way?

The idea is to have a flag that tells me that in that coordinates there are other sites as well.

My class looks like this:

```
public class WayPoint
{
  public int MPID { get; set; }
  public string MAPPOINT { get; set; }
  public double X { get; set; }
  public double Y { get; set; }
  public string MPCODE { get; set; }
  public bool MultipleSite { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking

Comment: Need more info?

Comment: `So I would like to update the value of their column MultipleSite to 1` In the UI? Or in the database? Or both?

Comment: I want to alterate the list only. After I will pass it to the front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several potential solutions, depending on what you want to achieve, and how you'd prefer to solve it.

You could use something like the following in C# after filling the list `data` as in your question, and then use the result to update the DB (if that is what you want to do):

```
foreach(wayPoint in data)
{
    if(data.Any(d => (d.MPID != wayPoint.MPID) 
                     && (d.X == wayPoint.X) 
                     && (d.Y == wayPoint.Y)))
    {
        wayPoint.MultipleSite = 1;
    }
}
```

If you don't need to update the DB, then that should be fine; otherwise, you could either use the result of the above to update your DB, or you might create a stored procedure in the database to do something similar.

One idea:

- Create a temp table with the values `MPID`, `X`, and `Y`, and populate it with copies of everything from your main table.
- Iterate over the resulting temp table and check against the main table with the same criteria as in the `if`-structure above (select and get the `MPID`-values for all rows with matching `X` and `Y`-values).
- For each row in the temp table, update the relevant rows in the main table, and then remove the updated rows from the temp-table (*Note: Removing all rows in the temp-table that correspond to updated rows in the main table means that you will have to query for
  at least one row less in the temp table; after all you don't need to check if you already know it has a `MultipleSite` value of `1`*).

This may sound heavy / slow, and perhaps there are more efficient ways to do what you want, but it should at least be doable and understandable this way.

**Either way, I can't see how you can get around iterating over all rows, since that is in essence, exactly what you want to do; to check for each row if there are others with the same values.**

Answer (score 1):

Given your data model (i.e., `WayPoint`), please try the following:

```
             data.GroupBy(o => new { X = o.X, Y = o.Y })
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    Items = g.Select(gp => new WayPoint
                        {
                            MPID = gp.MPID,
                            MAPPOINT = gp.MAPPOINT,
                            X = g.Key.X,
                            Y = g.Key.Y,
                            MPCODE = gp.MPCODE,
                            MultipleSite = g.Count() > 1
                        })
                }
              )
              .SelectMany(g=>g.Items)
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one SQL command...

```
UPDATE MAPPOINT 
SET [MultipleSite] = 1
FROM MAPPOINT m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT X, Y FROM MAPPOINT
    GROUP BY X, Y
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) gr on gr.X = m.X 
and gr.Y = m.Y
```

And if you just want to select these records to manipulate in memory...

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM MAPPOINT m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT X, Y FROM MAPPOINT
    GROUP BY X, Y
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) gr on gr.X = m.X 
and gr.Y = m.Y
```